# Async, await store элементы в getters VueX

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuex

В компрненте getCities приходит пустой массив. Если задать setTimeout елементу getCities, то мы получаем нужный результат. Не могу разобраться как добавить async, await 
в store getCitiesByCountryCode.

```js
<!-- STORE -->
export default new Vuex.Store({
  state: {
        cities: []
    },
    mutations: {
        updateCities(state, cities) {
            state.cities = cities
        }
    },
    actions: {
        async fetchLocations({dispatch, commit}) {
            try {
                let cities = await axios.get(`https://aviasales-api.herokuapp.com/cities`)
                commit('updateCities', cities.data)

            } catch(e) {
                console.log(e)
                return Promise.reject(e)
            }
        }
    },
    getters: {
        allCities(state) {
            return state.cities
        },
        getCitiesByCountryCode: state => code => {
            return state.cities.filter(city => city.country_code === code)
        }
    }
})


<!-- КОМПОНЕНТ -->
<template>

</template>

<script>
  export default {
    computed: mapGetters(['allCities']),
    methods: mapActions(['fetchLocations']),
    mounted() {
      this.fetchLocations()

      let getCities = this.$store.getters.getCitiesByCountryCode("PE")
      console.log(getCities)
    }
  }
</script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Не нужно добавлять в store. Просто укажите так:

```
 ...
 async mounted() {
  await this.fetchLocations()

  let getCities = this.$store.getters.getCitiesByCountryCode("PE")
  console.log(getCities)
 ...
```